# i want to code for " splitting the sentence " in java manually without using any of String or StringTokenizer etc methods

Tags: java

please, i search for this but every time i found codes with charAt(),length(),toCharArray() etc but i want to code absolutely manual code. Please help me out.

this is what rough idea i have:-

```
String[] s = new String[100];   
// declare temporary string variable   
String token = new String();  
// loop through string fetching one char at a time  
int index = 0;  
for(i = 0 to length of string) {  
    char ch = character at position i  
    if (ch == ' ') {  
        s[index++] = token;  
        token = ""; 
    } else {  
        token = token + ch;   
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Manual code? What? Why? Not sure anyone can understand the question

Comment: You can look in the java source code

Comment: this is the one interviewer asked me in an interview @Michael

Comment: There is no more manual way to get "length of string" other then calling `.length()` (and maybe more convoluted ways like `.toCharArray().length`). Java is a high level object oriented language.

Comment: I wouldn't want to work for a company that asked me to get the length of a string without being able to use the `length()` method.

Comment: If this is an interview question, it's a pretty miserable one.

Comment: Exactly guys i agree with you all, then what should i conclude is it possible to do this or not?(haha i mean of cource in a considerable amount of time). Because I also agree that if we have easy methods ready to that already it was just logical/technical test thats why i needed to do that.

Comment: @AkshayMahajan I'm sure it's possible to do this. You are just going to have to create your own classes and data structures to do so. You have to decide if it's worth your time and would you absolutely want to work for this company. Up to you. Good luck!

Comment: @ Michael Markidis- thanks, i was wanted to know that **am i the only one having this question** like what is the need to do this. thanks, guys i own my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the previous comments. You would have to iterate over the string until you reached an IndexOutOfBoundsException, but even in that case you would need the built in try/catch.

If you wanted to minimize the built in functions, you could use C where strings are null terminated. In Java, a char array is the lowest level you can work with, but even in that case you would have to do toCharArray().